# getting xcode dsymutil warning

Tags: xcode, dsymutil

I am getting the dsymutil warning as follow:

[image]

Can somebody tell me how to fix this? thank you i'm new to Xcode

Update

[image]

Comment: If is more warning? such as `note: xxx`

Comment: I've updated my question, just realised theres mmdrawer in every warning, does that point to anything? thanks

Comment: So, if the MMDrawerController is a three-party library Controller?

Comment: yes i downloaded it to implement in my app

Answer (score 3):

I got similar, but warning has gone after I did 'Clean build folder'

Xcode -> Product -> 'Clean build folder' menu. You need to press 'alt' key to see this menu item.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked for me using  Xcode -> Product -> Clean

Answer (score 0):

The warning have point out the reason:

> No such file or directory

---

Because your `MMDrawerController` is belongs to a three-party library.
You should contact the author to disenable debugging of the library module then publish that.

Comment: so the way to fix this is to delete the references to these files? how can i do that if thats the case? thanks

Comment: @H.Lamb If there is more information ? can you post them?